# detecting color of the tractor from a perspective view

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, deep-learning, detection

I want to detect the color of the tractors (in trucks). I trained a model to detect the tractor part as ROI(Regio of interest). I detect ROI by drawing a rectangle around the tractor.
my question is how can I detect the color of cab/tractor? I need the method to be robust to lighting conditions and weather differential. 
example of the truck can be found here

the perspective view makes the problem challenging since the ROI is a rectangle, part of the background gets into the ROI.

Edited: I use kmeans and put the number of clusters= 2, for the following image

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

it outputs this color

It seems as if conventional image processing techniques are not robust enough.

Could you please tell me what method would be more accurate?

Comment: You should probably move this question to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Color Quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization) on the rectangle.  This will try to reduce the number of colors to a palette that could still accurately represent the image.  The usual algorithms return them sorted by most dominant color.

Hopefully there is more truck than background in the rectangle.  You could also crop in a margin of the rectangle if you think truck is usually centered in the rectangle.

Here's an example using python and scikit: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_color_quantization.html

You should use a very small number (4?) of colors in the expected palette.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I added my result to my post, it seems as if conventional image processing does not work well.

Comment: Allow more colors.

Comment: when I increase the cluster to 4-5, it gets into black, the prediction gets worth.

Comment: When i upload to http://www.colorfavs.com/ and other palette generators, it does a pretty good job

Comment: I would increase the number even more and then analyze the hue of the top colors